# Problem using mod_rewrite to support canconical URL

Tags: apache2, https, mod-rewrite

I'm having some difficulty with mod_rewrite and suspect I'm making a basic error.

My goal is to set-up a canonical form on my server so that all access (by domain or IP address) goes without variation to the https:// and www sub-domain. e.g. https://www.example.com

Here are my rewrite rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^99\.100\.101\.102
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This seems to work, except:
https://example.com
... which does not get re-rewritten with the www. sub-domain and trips a certificate warning.

What schoolboy error have I made? :-)

/Warren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file works for me if I add this at the beginning

```
RewriteEngine on
```

But i guess you have enabled `mod_rewrite` by default.

Since you use permanent 301 header it may be a browser cache issue from an earlier versions of rules..?

Did you tried to reset browser cache? Or tried another browser that you haven't used before?

You can also try adding `[OR]` at the end of the first condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^99\\.100\\.101\\.102 [OR]
```

Comment: Yes, I do have "RewriteEngine on". I presume I only need that once at the top?

Good theory on the browser cache but still no joy. It's just the example.com on https:// that's not working.